# Possible To Raise Associate Salary In GTA Online As A CEO?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So I've been a CEO in GTA: Online for about 2 weeks now and my brother plays on his computer as well. I invite him as an associate to my company so that we can pickup packages and make deliveries and such together. Every so often (Maybe 10-15 minutes), he receives a paycheck which started at $5,000 and is now at about $7000. Before I became a CEO, I joined a company as an associate and immediately got $10000 for my paycheck.

I was wondering if there was a setting in the SecuroServe CEO section in the menu to increase salary so I can increase my brother's salary to $10000.

I looked at all the SecuroServe menus I could find but I found nothing on it. Is salary even controlled by me or is it based off rank/level? I know it's not based off your time as an associate for the company because I was getting paid $10000 and I had just joined the company. Please let me know if you know of a way to increase the salary of an associate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The associate pay starts at 5000 and increases by roughly 500 for every successful job you do. This includes vip jobs and cargo missions as best I can tell. It caps out at 10k so you received 10k because that group had already maxed out their jobs before you joined.

Answer (score 5):

The pay for the associates start at $5000 every fifteen minutes. For each successful crate mission, they get a bonus of $500 added to their salary. Each time you get killed, their salary is decreased by $250. The maximum they can get paid is $10,000.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience as an associate, my salary would increase the longer I was an associate. It will go up 10% each paycheck. I have also learned that if a Ceo doesn't leave the session he is in, then the associated wages stay the same. As for joining and your pay being at the max pay, I can not answer how that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how long the CEO has been buying crates. The longer the CEO has been buying crates the more the associates get paid. The most an associate can get paid is 10k.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences being an associate, I earned 5,000 every 5-10 minutes (depending on what we were doing) and it increased by 500 every 15 min or so.